# Can't login to Windows 10 after updating to Creator Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

I tried the pin, then the password. 
I can login with safe mode, but if I boot normally I'm returned to the login screen after I enter my password. I can't get to the desktop.

Comment: Try to login with safe mode, then disable all startup programs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm staring at a black screen now. Maybe I did the disabling wrong.  Should I uncheck the msconfig option for loading startup programs or disable them another way?

Comment: With windows 10 you disable the startup items using Task Manager, using shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Esc, and navigate to Startup tab. Do you still have access to safe mode?

Comment: Yes. So, I just discovered explorer is running, but I have to use task manager to call an explorer window.  I can run programs that way too, but the desktop is black. No icons, no wallpaper

Comment: I suggest you do a refresh, using a Windows installation USB. I've got that happened to me once, and refresh is the fastest option. However if you want to try the root cause, please provide us with the before and after update version. I'm guessing you updated to Creator update?

Comment: Yep. Creator update. Has this has been happening to a lot of users? I don't know what version I had previously. How can I find out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58227/discussion-between-vylix-and-stack-johan).

Comment: @StackJohan No; It's not happening to lots of people your problem is a specific incompatible with your unique configuration

Comment: Do you have another user account on that PC? I would simply backup your personal data, delete the user account from the Settings > Accounts window, then log back in. I just recently did this for a family friend after creators update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reported in several other tech forums.  Boot to safemode with networking.  In other's cases, there were additional updates that get installed and reboot.  After, they could log in again.  Another option was clicking the power icon on the login screen, hold shift and click reboot. Boot to startup repair.  This should load advanced startup.   Choose troubleshoot > advanced > Startup repair.

Answer (score 0):

go Microsoft website just type in google windows 10 login should be the first link on page sign into your Microsoft account the same one you use to login to windows then once that's done change your Microsoft password and then try logging into windows using the new password you created that's what I did and it worked for me